# Can I have conditional constants in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have an entity that has a generic integer parameter `fs_in_khz` that can be 5, 10 or 2:

```
entity test_control_source is
    generic(
        -- This should only be 5, 10 or 20
        fs_in_khz : integer := 20
    );
```

It would be nice if I could take advantage of VHDL's features and simply restrict the type to those values, perhaps using something like:

```
type control_source_freq is (F5_KHZ, F10_KHZ, F20_KHZ);
...
entity test_control_source is
generic(
    -- This should only be 5, 10 or 20
    fs_in_khz : control_source_freq := F20_KHZ
);
```

However, later on in the architecture of this entity, I have

```
architecture source_behaviour of test_control_source is
    constant cs_period : integer := 5000 * clock_rate / fs_in_khz;
begin
    ...
```

I prefer having this parameter computed outside of the processes that use it, rather repeating the computation everywhere it's needed. Can I restrict the allowed values of my `fs_in_khz` generic parameter *and* keep my constant `cs_period` factored out of the processes where it's used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your enumerated type in a package, as you suggest

Also create a function called `calculate_period` which takes in `clock_rate` and your `fs` type and returns the appropriate integer.

Alternatively, add some `assert` statements to the component using that generic and verify that it is of the correct values.  Test this with your synthesis tool to see what happens if the asserts trigger though - often, even if you use `severity failure` it'll just give a warning!

Comment: Created a small package with an `enum` and a function, works perfectly and lays the groundwork for factoring out other hardware settings for testing!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to declare the constant `F_KHZ` in a **package** and compute the constant `cs_period` in the same package after the declaration of `F_KHZ`. This would not restrict the values of `F_KHZ` however, but you'd only have to change it in one place making an error very unlikely. This is of course assuming that you need your `F_KHZ` constant to be the same in the entire architecture.